# How to fix Parallels Management Node if DHCP server filters MAC address

Tags: mac-osx-server, mac-address

I'm evaluating Parallels Server on Mac OS X  Lion Server, and during installation it sets up a "Management Node" VM for managing the other VMs. The problem is that my DHCP server is filtering MAC addresses, so for now the installation fails since connection can't be established.

How can I know its MAC address so that I can authorize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually restarting the server allowed me to see the MAC address in Management Console.